# Constructing a normed space from a metric on a vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis

I'm attempting to verify a statement made by the author of a textbook:

Given a metric d on a vector space $X$, setting $||x|| = d(x,0)$  defines a norm on $X$ if:

1) $d(x,y) = d(x+z,y+z) $

2) $d(ax,ay) = |a|d(x,y) $

for any vectors $x,y,z$ and scalar $a$.

Here is what I've tried:

Suppose the metric $d$ is such that assigning $d(x,0)$ to every $x$ is a valid norm, where $||x|| := d(x,0)$.

Then we can use the norm ||,|| to define a new metric d' as follows:

$d'(x,y) := ||x-y||$.

Then we have $ d'(x+z,y+z) = ||(x+z)-(y+z)|| = ||x-y|| = d'(x,y)$.
And $d'(ax,ay) = ||ax-ay|| = ||a(x-y)|| = |a|||x-y|| = |a|d'(x,y$).

So I've showed this metric $d'$ satisfies 1) and 2). and I know that $d'(x,0) = ||x|| = d(x,0)$. But it is not clear to me that $d=d'$, and I don't know how to proceed/show that $d$ must satisfy 1) and 2).

Comment: You know there are metrics which are not translation invariant, which means that it could fail to satisfy $d(x,y)=d(x+z,y+z)$, but the $d'$ is translation invariant, not sure this will give you some insight or not.

Comment: Right, so the problem is saying given that || . || is a norm, show that d is translation invariant, and d(ax, ay) = |a|d(x,y).

Comment: Not sure about the other direction if it is true or not, so this is an exercise from a book? If so, which book?

Comment: author said this in Linear Analysis 2nd Edition by Bela Bollobas, page 21. You seem to be correct, someone posted a counterexample below.

Comment: I have a simple question, I don't think it is worth to be asked as a question on its own. So please can anyone help me, is it true that for any distance $d(ax,ay)=|a|d(x,y)$?? Or there is a distance that doesn't have this property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The converse is false. Consider the metric $d$ on $\mathbb{R}$ given by 
$$
d(x,y) = \begin{cases}
\lvert{x\rvert}+\lvert{y\rvert} &\text{if } x\neq y\\
0 &\text{if } x=y
\end{cases}
$$
Clearly, $d(x,0) = \lvert x\rvert$ defines a norm (the usual norm on the reals). On the other hand, property (1) is not satisfied. To see this, take for instance $x=2, y=3, z=-1$.